# integral curve for $X(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+(xy)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, geometry, partial-differential-equations

Find the integral curve for, 
$X(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+(xy)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$.

You can use the following results (if needed)

If $(x(t),y(t))$ is the integral curve

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{g(x,y)}{f(x,y)}$ is a homogenous function of degree 0.

we can cover it to a separable ODE for $\frac{y}{x}$. see this result 
[Converting a differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1457644/converting-a-differential-equation)

Comment: On $\mathbb{R}^2$ I imagine?

Comment: @Moya I think it is $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}$

Comment: @Moya I edited the question with some possible hints, please see

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method you mention in the link: if $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ and $\gamma'(t)=X\circ\gamma(t)\Rightarrow$

\begin{align*}
x'(t)&=x(t)^2+y(t)^2\\
y'(t)&=x(t)y(t)\end{align*}Then you need to use the chain rule/inverse function theorem (you need to assume, as noted in the comments, that the domain of this is $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$, otherwise you cannot use the inverse function theorem on $x(t)$) to get
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\cdot (\frac{dx}{dt})^{-1}=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$$Now follow the link: set $u=\frac{y}{x}$, then $$\frac{dy}{dx}=u'x+u=\frac{u}{1+u^2}\Rightarrow u'x=-\frac{u^3}{1+u^2}$$
Then go from there: solve for $u(x)$.

You could also try polar, but that seems like a bad idea. $X=r^2\cos\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial r}-r\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}+r^2\cos\theta\sin^2\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+r\cos^2\theta\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}$